# Android app is crashing after adding admod java code

Tags: java, android, crash, admob

Class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AdView mAdView;
    TextView percents;
    Singleton m_Inst = Singleton.getInstance();


    private int volume = 50;
    private int boost = 0;


    private AudioManager audio;

    public MainActivity() {

    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    @SuppressLint("WrongViewCast")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AdView adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");

        MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");

        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

**LOGCAT**

````
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.loadAd(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest)' on a null object reference
        at com.bassbooster.android_simple_eq.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:62)*```
````

Comment: which place to add this  `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` line your error is because of not inflate layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mAdView is null.

This is probably, because you do not inflate a layout.

Try inflating a layout which contains the adView with an id first.

You can do this inside the onCreate of the activity with [setContentView(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#setContentView(android.view.View))

Edit:

As asked in the comment, I am modifying your code:

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private AdView mAdView;
TextView percents;
Singleton m_Inst = Singleton.getInstance();


private int volume = 50;
private int boost = 0;


private AudioManager audio;

public MainActivity() {

}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
@SuppressLint("WrongViewCast")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //first change
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)


    AdView adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");

    MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");


    mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

main_activity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
     android:id="@+id/adView"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

As you can see, the `findViewById` points to the id of the AdView inside the main_activity.xml. Therefore you don't call a null object reference.
This would be a basic setup, that should work.

If you have further questions, please let me know.

Comment: Thank you, But to be honest I am so confused, I am newbie, Plz could u write down the code. That would be a great help.

Comment: Thanks you soo much it worked, But Admob banner is hiding behind the home screen. what should I do?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with hiding behind the home screen? Is there another gui component in front of it?

Comment: I am using the relative layout and linear layout. When I resize and move the home screen wallpaper, I can see the banner ad behind it.

Comment: Can you provide your layout file? Then it would be much easier for me to help you!

Comment: Thanks for your help Sir, I resolved it by myself, Now it's showing. I placed the code in the wrong section. Once again thank you.

Comment: Nice to hear that! If you feel like I was helpful to you, consider marking my answer as the accepted one! Thanks in advance!